# Casting element in python

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, casting

So, i want to select a value from a dropdown in python. The code look something like that:

```
def selectDropdown(self, locator, value):
    select_box = self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator)
    select_box.click()
    options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")]
    for element in options:
        print ("element ---->", element)
        print ("value ---->", value)
        if element == value:
            element.click()
            break
```

The code work, but the element and value are different for some reason. Look the outputs from the prints:

```
('element ---->', <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003080908>)
('value ---->', '\xce\xa4\xcf\x8d\xcf\x80\xce\xbf\xcf\x82 \xce\x92 \xce\xa0\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb8\xce\xb1\xcf\x81\xcf\x87\xce\xb9\xce\xba\xce\xbf\xcf\x8d')
('element ---->', <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003080C18>)
('value ---->', '\xce\xa4\xcf\x8d\xcf\x80\xce\xbf\xcf\x82 \xce\x92 \xce\xa0\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb8\xce\xb1\xcf\x81\xcf\x87\xce\xb9\xce\xba\xce\xbf\xcf\x8d')
('element ---->', <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003080B70>)
('value ---->', '\xce\xa4\xcf\x8d\xcf\x80\xce\xbf\xcf\x82 \xce\x92 \xce\xa0\xce\xb5\xce\xb9\xce\xb8\xce\xb1\xcf\x81\xcf\x87\xce\xb9\xce\xba\xce\xbf\xcf\x8d')
```

So what can i do so the statement if work properly?

Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="chosen-drop">
  <div class="chosen-search">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="" />
  </div>
  <ul class="chosen-results">
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">Τύπος Α</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Τύπος Β</li>
    <li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Τύπος Γ</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is element.text == value what you need?

Comment: i tried that but it doesn't work. I want the values to be the same so the if statement work, but the element show the address and the value is utf-8.

Comment: You mean something like that(?):
for element in options:
        fetcher = element.get_attribute(value)
        print ("element ---->", element)
        print ("value ---->", value)
        if fetcher== value:
            element.click()
            break

Cause i tried that too and i have an error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: what text is there in your list?

Comment: element.text = ('element ---->', u'\u03a4\u03cd\u03c0\u03bf\u03c2 \u0391 \u03a0\u03b5\u03b9\u03b8\u03b1\u03c1\u03c7\u03b9\u03ba\u03bf\u03cd')
('element ---->', u'\u03a4\u03cd\u03c0\u03bf\u03c2 \u0392 \u03a0\u03b5\u03b9\u03b8\u03b1\u03c1\u03c7\u03b9\u03ba\u03bf\u03cd')
('element ---->', u'\u03a4\u03cd\u03c0\u03bf\u03c2 \u0393 \u03a0\u03b5\u03b9\u03b8\u03b1\u03c1\u03c7\u03b9\u03ba\u03bf\u03cd')

Comment: You can definitely not compare element with value directly, since selenium is returning you an object and value is a string. You have to use the text in the element. Isn't the problem in this line options = [x for x in select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")]? Couldn't you change it for options = select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li") instead?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas i posted the HTML code in the post.
Even without the x for x the output is still the same.

Comment: @fdgenie I've rolled back your latest edit. If you want to post a solution do not edit the solution into the question. Post it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution:

```
def selectDropdown(self, locator, value):
    select_box = self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator)
    select_box.click()
    options = select_box.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for element in options:
        if element.text in value.decode("utf-8"):
            element.click()
            break
```